# Expression.Body as MemberExpression returns null for primitive property

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am using this code to set the value of a property via reflection :

```
public static void Set<T>(this T target, Expression<Func<T, object>> memberLamda, object value)
{
    var memberSelectorExpression = memberLamda.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (memberSelectorExpression != null)
    {
        var property = memberSelectorExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
        if (property != null)
        {
            property.SetValue(target, value, null);
        }
    }
}
```

But for some reason when I do :

```
myObject.Set(x=>x.ID, 1);
```

Where ID is of type int, I can see that memberSelectorExpression is null. However I have no issue with properties of a reference type.

I am not very familiar yet with expression trees, what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Look at the actual expression tree and see what the expression *actually* is, given that you now know it's not a `MemberExpression`.

Comment: Or if your code should fail quickly if the body isn't a member expression, just cast instead of using `as`...

Comment: @JonSkeet another good idea, thanks... I have a sense that I'm getting tired, this looks more and more like a trivial question

Comment: @Servy The expression  body is of type Convert(x.Id)
How can I do extract a Propertyinfo from this ?

Comment: @red2nb Look up the documentation for that type and see what members it has.  One of them will be the expression being converted.

Comment: I'm sure you wished you could downvote me two time. Thanks. Actually I made a mistake, the property is of type UnaryExpression, I think I begin to have a sense of what to do

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to use the following signature :

```
public static void Set<T, TProp>(this T target, Expression<Func<T, TProp>> memberLamda, 
  TProp value)
```

To make sure a MemberExpression is correctly inferred. The "object" generic constraint is not specific enough.

Comment: Whats about .NET Core, is there any alternative? Seems that **TProp** is not avaliable there. But the problem is the same, using Expression<Func<T, object>> I got null...

Comment: @Lion It will always be available, TProp represents a generic type which is a compiler-feature (independent from .NET Core) - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The thing to be aware of is that your expression body will most likely be wrapped in a Convert expression, representing the fact that your property is being implicitly cast as an object.  So you'll probably need code something like this in your Setmethod.

```
var expressionBody = memberLamda.Body;
if (expressionBody is UnaryExpression expression && expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
{
    expressionBody = expression.Operand;
}
var memberSelectorExpression = (MemberExpression)expressionBody;
```