# How can I pass multiple lambda expression to a method then obtain the property info for each expression?

Tags: c#, lambda

In a C# project, I want to create a function that allows me to pass lambda expression which I can parse each expression into a PropertyInfo where I can extract the property name and the property value.

Here is a stripped down version of my code

```
public IEnumerable<Student> Make(IEnumerable<User> users, Expression<Func<User, dynamic>> primaryProperty, params Expression<Func<User, dynamic>>[] otherProperties)
{
    var students = new List<Student>();

    foreach(User user in users)
    {
        var student = new Student();
        var mainProp = GetPropertyInfo(user, primaryProperty);
        object mainValue = prop.GetValue(user, null);
        // Do somthing with mainProp.Name...
        // Do something with mainValue ...

        foreach(Expression<Func<User, dynamic> exp in otherProperties ?? new Expression<Func<User, dynamic>>[] {})
        {
            var prop = GetPropertyInfo(user, exp);
            object value = prop.GetValue(user, null);
            // Set the property student property
            // Do somthing with prop.Name...
            // Do something with value...
        }

        students.Add(student);
    }

    return strudents;
}


private static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo<TSource, TProperty>(TSource source, Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> propertyLambda)
{
    Type type = typeof(TSource);

    if (!(propertyLambda.Body is MemberExpression expression))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"Expression '{propertyLambda}' refers to a method, not a property.");
    }

    PropertyInfo propInfo = expression.Member as PropertyInfo;

    if (propInfo == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"Expression '{propertyLambda}' refers to a field, not a property.");
    }

    if (type != propInfo.ReflectedType && !type.IsSubclassOf(propInfo.ReflectedType))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"Expression '{propertyLambda}' refers to a property that is not from type {type}.");
    }

    return propInfo;
}
```

When I pass property of a primitive type to the function, the `GetPropertyInfo` fails as `propertyLambda.Body as MemberExpression expression` returns null.

From google, it seems that the cause of this issue is because I am using `dynamic` as a return value to the function where it should be something like `TProperty` instead. Here is a reference [Expression.Body as MemberExpression returns null for primitive property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31121299/expression-body-as-memberexpression-returns-null-for-primitive-property/31121750#31121750)

However, I am not sure how to rewrite my `Make` method to use `TProperty` instead of `dynamic` every property can have a different type.

**Question** How can I pass multiple lambda expression to the `Make` method then obtain the property info for each expression?

Comment: What if you change to `object`? Everything inherits from that base class.

Comment: Try this: `if (!(propertyLambda.Body is MemberExpression))`

Comment: @preciousbetine this is what I am doing please look at the code in the question

Comment: Remove `expression` from the if statement.

Comment: @preciousbetine I am not following you. Please read this which seems to be the same problem I am having https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31121299/expression-body-as-memberexpression-returns-null-for-primitive-property/31121750#31121750

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine to use `object` instead of `dynamic` in your expression types.

```
public IEnumerable<Student> Make(IEnumerable<User> users, Expression<Func<User, object>> primaryProperty, params Expression<Func<User, object>>[] otherProperties)
```

The thing to be aware of is that your expression body will most likely be wrapped in a Convert expression, representing the fact that your property is being implicitly cast as an object.  So you'll probably need code something like this in your GetPropertyInfo method.

```
var expressionBody = propertyLambda.Body;
if (expressionBody is UnaryExpression expression && expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
{
    expressionBody = expression.Operand;
}
```